# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently work on a projet which display a recipe with ingredients checked in a formular. I near to the end but i really not understand what is my error. If someone can explain to me :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column '$idingredient' in 'where clause' in
>   /homepages/30/d675437312/htdocs/assets/recettemalin/recetteselectionnee.php:55
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /homepages/30/d675437312/htdocs/assets/recettemalin/recetteselectionnee.php(55):
>   PDO->query(' SELECT DIST...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/30/d675437312/htdocs/assets/recettemalin/recetteselectionnee.php
>   on line 55

Here's my code where it block :

```
if (isset($_POST['ingredients'])) {
        $idingredient = implode(",", $_POST['ingredients']);
        echo $idingredient.'<br>';
        $recette = $bdd->query('    SELECT DISTINCT r.*
                                    FROM ingredient i
                                    INNER JOIN contient c
                                       ON i.id_i = c.id_i
                                    INNER JOIN recette r
                                       ON c.id_r = r.id_r
                                    WHERE i.id_i IN ($idingredient)');
    while ($donnees = $recette->fetch()) {
        echo $donnees['nom_r'];
        echo $donnees['type_r'];
        echo $donnees['description'];
    }
}
```

When I echo `$idingredient` I get a list of id of ingredient like this : 6,9,11,12,1,5 but it seem's to not be liked by the clause where and I'm wondering why ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use " instead of ' in the query string to evaluate variables:

```
$recette = $bdd->query("  SELECT DISTINCT r.*
                                    FROM ingredient i
                                    INNER JOIN contient c
                                       ON i.id_i = c.id_i
                                    INNER JOIN recette r
                                       ON c.id_r = r.id_r
                                    WHERE i.id_i IN ($idingredient)");
```

Or you can juste concatinate the variable to the string:

```
'.....' . $idingredient . '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

First, parameterize your queries.  Don't just dump random strings into the query, because it can cause syntax errors.

Second, your specific problem is that you are putting in a string, but there are no string delimiters.  Hence, the value is interpreted as an identifier -- specifically a column alias.  I don't recommend this solution, but `WHERE i.id_1 IN ('$idingredient')` probably does what you want.

Third, don't use `IN` for a comparison to a single value.  It is misleading.  Furthermore, the value is a single value, even if it has commas . . . `'butter,margarine'` is one value with a comma in it, not two values.

Comment: `(' . $idingredient . ')`